# How to run seeder in Laravel 5.1 with class parameter

Tags: laravel-5, seeding, laravel-seeding

I Use laravel 5.1 , I received "Class MySeederClass does not exist " when use --class in php artisan db::seed(like php artisan db::seed --class=MySeederClass) , but when I run this command without class parameter, every thing is ok, what is this parameter problam??

Comment: Do you specify the full namespace of the seeder class?

Comment: @TheFallen yes, I test it also

Comment: Can you paste the header of your MySeeder class here including imports?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody will have the same error just try to update your composer auto loader class with command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```